# best solution for hirercical and non typed data

Tags: database, performance, nosql, persistence, bigdata

I have a db schema like this:

- ELEMENT(uuid[string], name[string], status[integer], ...)
- APPLICATION(uuid[string], name[string], config[string], status[integer], parent[foreign key on self or foreign key on ELEMENT], ...)
- ATTRIBUTE(uuid[string], name[string],type[string], parent[foreign key on APPLICATION], ...)
- VALUES(created[datetime], data[varchar|text|integer|float|boolean|datetime])

And I have this constraints:

1. Application must have a fk on ELEMENT or on SELF
2. Attribute could grow up to 250000 values
3. For every Attribute I have 20.000 Values
4. Values data column can have different types
5. On user request I need to serve all Application that match a specific Element
6. On user request I need to serve all Attributes and their last value that match a specific application
7. On user request I need to server all Values of a specific Attribute in a arbitrary datetime range
8. At regular intervals(x minutes) new values are added and the oldest are removed
9. When new values are added I might need to access last X values of an Attribute
10. when someone is modifying a item of ELEMENT, APPLICATION or ATTRIBUTE i need to lock that item
11. I need a persistent data storage and good performance when users makes some requests

I cannot use a classic RDBMS because of constraint 4 and i think a relation database is not the best solution in any case. I think best solution is to use a NOSQL database but which one? There are lot of solutions with pro and cons but i don't know which approaches better to my needs.

Thanks